# automatically Close flash player after playing

Tags: flash-cs4, overlay

I need to close a flash player which is overlayed over another portion. When the video is over, the 'div' i created (overlayed to display video)must vanish showing the orginal content. tried everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a javascript function to remove the opened `<div>` from the DOM tree.

For this use the [`Externalinterface.call`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) method. You just need to create a javascript function and embed the flash object with the `allowscriptaccess` option set to always.

The JavaScript function could be like this:

```
function removeDiv( divID ) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

And the corresponding ActionScript:

```
ExternalInterface.call("removeDiv", "theIdOfTheDiv");
```